# Tree with multiline text in node and "X" on some text

Tags: trees

I am looking to replicate in TeX this tree diagram I made in PowerPoint. What makes it harder than you basic tree is the multiline labels at terminal nodes, the Xs on some terminal node labels and the "R.1/R.2" labels between branches.

It would really bother me to keep the PowerPoint version, but also to spend 1 month trying to figure it out.

Grateful for any help.

[image: diagram of interest]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple to do with `forest`. There are plenty of similar trees on the site. I've chosen to add the crosses separately rather than adding the decoration to the `forest` nodes directly, because this better allows to control their size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={l sep'=1cm,s sep'=1cm}
[Undertaking\\ART,name=Art
    [Unsuccesful,name=U
        [Spontaneous\\Conception\\(Only SC child)\\{[A]} ]
        [No Spontaneous\\Conception\\(no conception)\\{[B]},name=B]
    ]
    [Successful
        [Spontaneous\\Conception\\(very rare)\\{[C]},name=C ]
        [No Spontaneous\\Conception\\(only ART child)\\{[D]}]
    ]
]
\node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1cm] at (B) {};
\node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1cm] at (C) {};
\node[below=1cm of Art] {R.1};
\node[below=.5cm of U] {R.2};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

If you don't like the joined branches that the `[linguistics]` library uses, don't load it and you'll get branches that aren't joined. In this case you need to add the `align=center` specification to the tree to allow linebreaks in the nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={l sep'=1cm,s sep'=1cm,align=center}
[Undertaking\\ART,name=Art
    [Unsuccesful,name=U
        [Spontaneous\\Conception\\(Only SC child)\\{[A]} ]
        [No Spontaneous\\Conception\\(no conception)\\{[B]},name=B]
    ]
    [Successful
        [Spontaneous\\Conception\\(very rare)\\{[C]},name=C]
        [No Spontaneous\\Conception\\(only ART child)\\{[D]}]
    ]
]
\node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1cm] at (B) {};
\node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1cm] at (C) {};
\node[below=1cm of Art] {R.1};
\node[below=.5cm of U] {R.2};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output without linguistics library]

Comment: This is spot on! Publishing also my own answer, built with the help of yours.

Comment: `l sep'=1cm, s sep'=1cm` is quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own answer, found with the help of @Alan Munn:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
      \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
      \usetikzlibrary{calc}
      \usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    level 1/.style = {black, sibling distance = 8cm},
    level 2/.style = {black, sibling distance = 4cm},
    level distance = 3cm, % Increase the level distance  
  ]

  \node [align=center] (undertaking) {Undertaking \\ ART cycle}
  child {node [align=center] (succ) {Unsuccessful}
  child {node (A) [align=center] {Spontaneous \\ Conception \\ {\small (only SC child)} \\ {[A]}}}
  child {node (B) [align=center] {No Spontaneous \\ Conception \\ {\small (no conception)} \\ {[B]}}}
  }
  child {node (unsucc) {Successful}
  child {node (C) [align=center] {Spontaneous \\ Conception \\ {\small (only SC child)} \\ {[C]}}}
  child {node (D) [align=center] {No Spontaneous \\ Conception \\ {\small (no conception)} \\ {[D]}}}
  };

  \node [align=center, below=1cm of undertaking] {\bfseries R.1};
  \node [align=center, below=1cm of succ] {\bfseries R.2};
  \node [align=center, below=1cm of unsucc] {\bfseries R.2};
  \node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1.5cm] at (B) {};
  \node[red,draw,cross out,minimum size=1.5cm] at (C) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, the `forest` syntax is much simpler than the base TikZ tree methods.

Comment: 100%, although I am not a big fan of those branches :D

Comment: That's a function of the `linguistics` library. If you don't like them you can get branches like the one in your tree. I've updated my answer.

Comment: wonderful, thanks a lot!